Looking for a battery charger circuit for a 12 V 7 Ah LiFePO4 battery and multiple batteries in parallel
I want to charge my lithium-ion battery as shown below, but I first want to explore going down the route of making my own PCB before I decide to buy an off-shelf device. I want to charge the battery at a constant current of around 5 A until it reaches 14.6 V. Then I will switch to a constant voltage of 14.6 V (3.65 V x 4). At this point, the current will start to drop as the battery State of Charge increases. I am not sure what design would be best to perform such a task.
The intention is to design the circuit to only perform charging of the battery.
Does anyone know where I can start in terms of looking at what circuitry or IC is out there that can assist me?
For now,

The next design after this will be to charge 3 batteries in parallel.  Can I just use the same circuitry as before or are there any new complications that will arise?
For the next design


Before you start this project you need to do a lot more research into how LIfePO4 batteries are charged. For most of the charge cycle you will not get 14.6V at 5A, you need to address cell balancing and protection and you need to weigh up the final charge voltage against cell life. IMHO 14.6V is too high.

@RoyC I have done all of the above with a charger I borrowed, I charged it at 14.6V at 5A. Nothing blew up or heated. I experimented for over a month. Hence my specs are correct for my application through experimentation. Do you have any advice on the questions posted?

I understood the meaning as the usual process for battery charging: CC until CV, a power source with a square operating region. And by "usual", I mean most chemistries use this or an approximation, or can use, give or take optimal life (NiCd, Pb, Li Ion, etc.) (NiMH being probably the most common and dramatic departure?).

@TimWilliams I see I used the completely wrong wording in my post. You obviously cannot do CC and CV at the same time. I see my post tends to that assumption of what I need. I will update it so it is more clear as in your comment.

Use a suitable buck converter for example https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/122037620559?chn=ps&_ul=GB. You may need to increase the input voltage to this a bit due to the regulator dropout. These are so inexpensive it is usually not messing around trying to recreate it.


I first want to explore going down the route of making my own PCB before I decide to buy an off-shelf device

An off-the-shelf Li-ion (including LiFePO4) charger is preferable to spinning your own: safe, well-designed, has solved problems you are not aware of yet, cheaper than the cost of the parts to make your own, in a reliable enclosure, has a warranty, and meets regulatory requirements.

Then I will switch to a constant voltage

To be clear, a CCCV charger doesn't "decide" to switch. The charger simply limits the current and sets the voltage. It's the physics of the battery that "decide" to switch. When it's nearly full, its voltage reaches the CV setting of the charger and naturally the physics of the cells start drawing less current.

looking at what circuitry or IC

Texas Instruments makes a nice range of Li-ion charger ICs: https://www.ti.com/battery-management/charger-ics/products.html
The spec sheet gives you suggested circuit diagrams.

charge 3 batteries in parallel

Be VERY careful! Before connecting Li-ion (including LiFePO4) batteries in parallel, make very sure that they are at the same voltage. It they aren't, there will be a significant current from the more charged batteries to the least charged one. That high current at best degrades the cells, and at worst causes damage, even a fire.

Very informative! Thank you.

The power available limits the charge current/rate possible,
trying to keep charge current/rate possible with one battery, the power supply will be overloaded.
Charging one 7.2 Ah battery to 14.6 V from 150 W needs a very efficient charger to keep a rate of 1C (7.2 A).
